# How to create a temporary text file in C++?

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to create a temporary text file in C++ and then delete it at the end
of the program. I haven't had much luck with Google.

Could you tell me which functions to use?

---

The answers below tell me how to create a temp file. What if I just want to 
create a file (tmp.txt) and then delete it? How would I do that?

Comment: and then delete it at the end of the file ?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: Yes. The temporary file will only contain temporary data. The output will be written to an existing output.txt file.

Comment: For directories: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379956/how-to-create-a-temporary-directory-in-c/58454949#58454949

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Maybe this will help

```
FILE * tmpfile ( void );
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/tmpfile/

> Open a temporary file
>
> Creates a temporary binary file, open
>   for update (wb+ mode -- see fopen for
>   details). The filename is guaranteed
>   to be different from any other
>   existing file. The temporary file
>   created is automatically deleted when
>   the stream is closed (fclose) or when
>   the program terminates normally.

See also

```
char * tmpnam ( char * str );
```

> Generate temporary filename
>
> A string containing a filename
>   different from any existing file is
>   generated. This string can be used to
>   create a temporary file without
>   overwriting any other existing file.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/tmpnam/

Comment: It is worth mentioning that there might be issues with tmpfile() and tmpnam() in some contexts e.g., http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/TemporaryFileSecurity.aspx

Comment: Tmpfile, of course, has the problem of returning a C file handle, not a c++ stream.

Comment: @rlbond: Indeed, thats why I included tmpnam.

Comment: it's very important to note that tmpnam() is not to be used.  its man page says: "Never use this function.  Use mkstemp(3) or tmpfile(3) instead."

Comment: Where exactly is the temporary file created?

Comment: The problem is, the second one is considered unsafe and gives you a warning, and the first one  you can't get the name of and delete after use.

Comment: tmpnam, while part of the POSIX standard, is deprecated, and should be discouraged. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35188145/1593077).

Answer (score 28):

Here's a complete example:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
  char filename[] = "/tmp/mytemp.XXXXXX"; // template for our file.        
  int fd = mkstemp(filename);    // Creates and opens a new temp file r/w.
                                 // Xs are replaced with a unique number.
  if (fd == -1) return 1;        // Check we managed to open the file.
  write(fd, "abc", 4);           // note 4 bytes total: abc terminating '\0'
  /* ...
     do whatever else you want.
     ... */
  close(fd);
  unlink(filename);              // Delete the temporary file.
}
```

If you know the name of the file you want to create (and are sure it won't already exist) then you can obviously just use `open` to open the file.

`tmpnam` and `tmpfile` should probably be avoided as they can suffer from race conditions - see [`man tmpfile(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/tmpfile.3.html) for the details.

Comment: The Linux man page for mkstemp(3) says that the last 6 characters in filename must be XXXXXX. See http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/mkstemp.3.html

Comment: Hmm, the OS X manpage for mkstemp says you can have a variable number of XXXs. however in the interests of clarity (and 'cos most people are probably using Linux) I've changed the above example.

Comment: Actually it's mktemp and tmpnam that suffer from the race conditions you mention, not tmpfile. tmpfile returns the a C file handle, so you won't get a C++ stream, but you don't get a race condition either. I think the man pages you want to reference above are for tmpname(3) http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/tmpnam.3.html and mktemp http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/mktemp.3.html

Answer (score 6):

This may be a little off-topic because the author wanted to create a tmp.txt and delete it after using it, but that is trivial - you can simple open() it and delete it (using boost::filesystem of course).

mkstemp() is UNIX-based. With Windows you use GetTempFileName() and GetTempPath() to generate a path to a temp file. Sample code from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363875%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 6):

On Linux (starting with kernel 3.11), there's flag to open(2) O_TMPFILE that creates a temporary file that doesn't have a name (i.e. it doesn't show up in the filesystem).  This has a few interesting features:

- No worries about unique names, it's just an inode, there is no name.
- No race conditions during creation (e.g. symlink attacks).
- No stray files if your app crashes, it's always automatically deleted.

Comment: Minimal runnable example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508998/what-is-an-anonymous-inode-in-linux/44388030#44388030 I wonder if glibc can use that to implement `tmpfile`, but lazy to check now.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder why most of you guys showed him the C way of doing it instead of the C++ way.
Here's [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/).
Try that, deleting a file is OS depended but you can use [boost.filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) to make things easy for you.

Comment: That's probably because the OP asked for a temporary file, and there are no standard C++ mechanisms for creating a unique filename.  There is nothing in libstdc++ or boost that truly replaces mkstemp().

Answer (score 2):

If you need a named file (for example, so you can pass the name to another process, perhaps a compiler or editor), then register a cleanup function that removes the file with `atexit()`.  You can use either C++ `<iostream>` or C `FILE *` (`<cstdio>`) to create the file.  The not completely standard but widely available `mkstemp()` function creates a file and tells you its name as well as returning a file descriptor (a third I/O mechanism); you could use the `fdopen()` function to convert the file descriptor into a `FILE *`.

If you don't need a named file a C-style `FILE *` is OK, then look at `tmpfile()` as suggested by @Tom.

Answer (score 1):

A clean, portable and non-deprecated way of creating a temporary file is provided by [`Boost`](https://www.boost.org):

```
auto temporary_file = boost::filesystem::temp_directory_path() / boost::filesystem::unique_path();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you have been successful in creating the temporary file, you can use the remove function to delete it.

The function is declared in stdio.h -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int remove(const char *pathname);
```

For example, if you want to delete a file named myfile.txt the code will be

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  if(remove("myfile.txt") == -1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"Remove failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I hope by now, you already know how to create the temp file, so this should resolve your query.
Hope it helps.