# Getting safe temp folder in Windows

Tags: windows, api, filesystems, temporary-files

I need to get a safe temp folder where I could store temporary files for my application, but so far my research has lead me to conclusion that all approaches I've found are flawed.

The first idea was to use `GetTempPath` function, but that causes two problems:

- The folder might not exist, so I would have to truncate folders one by one up to root, and recreate them if they do not exist back to full path (error prone, tedious)
- From "Larry Osterman's WebLog" [click](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2010/10/19/because-if-you-do_2c00_-stuff-doesn_2700_t-work-the-way-you-intended_2e00_.aspx) it seems that `GetTempPath` might fallback to USERPROFILE or Windows directory and extract whole lot of files right in there, which is SUPER BAD(TM)!

In the same post, there is a suggestion to use GetEnvironmentVariable, but this seems a dangerous function to me (missing TMP & TEMP envvars for instance).

Is there a cleaner function I could use? Seems that SHGetKnownFolderPath has no clue what temp folder is.

Comment: Directory.Create creates all directories on the way that do not exist and does nothing if the directory does exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program is probably not the only one to rely on `GetTempPath`, so it's reasonable to expect it to return a proper writable path. Especially since Windows automatically initializes the TMP and TEMP environment variables for you; someone would have to go to some trouble to override them, and it would be their responsibility to make sure the change did not mess up their system.

I would go ahead and assume `GetTempPath` works properly, and worry about failures when you try to create the temporary file - there are other errors that might occur at that time that you need to check for anyway.

Comment: I decided to go with GetEnvVar as in article. This avoids problems with longer usernames and should be enough. If there is no TMP or TEMP variable, I think it's enough to assume that system is pretty much unusable.

Comment: -1 as the documentation specifically says _"Note that the function **does not verify that the path exists, nor does it test to see if the current process has any kind of access rights** to the path"_.

Comment: @David, of course it doesn't make that guarantee, that's not its job. Checking the folder would take lots of extra work that shouldn't be necessary on a properly configured system. I stand behind my answer.

Answer (score 0):

An idea would be to get the path where your application is (`GetModuleFileNameEx` combined with `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` and `GetCurrentProcess`) since this directory cannot be deleted under windows as long as your application is running from it (maybe I'm wrong ...some years ago I couldn't do this :) ) and in this directory create a temporary directory.

Comment: Generally the user can't write to program files folder. No dice.

Answer (score 0):

Your first bullet point is the solution. Wrap it up in a method so that you don't duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379956/how-to-create-a-temporary-directory-in-c/3380583#3380583), Boost's Filesystem library can be used for this.