# POSIX/MinGW compatibility: mkdir('/tmp/randompath') fails

Tags: c++, c, windows, mingw, posix

I need to create temporary folder in C/C++ library, and make it compatible with Windows/MinGW.
While `mkdir("/tmp/something")` works well (with permissions parameter of course) under Linux/macOS/whatever else, it fails under MinGW with `ENOENT` error.

Do I correctly understand that since `_mkdir()` is Windows API call then it should contain Windows path (i.e. will not be translated from `/tmp/...`) ?

And, then, what will be correct solution to access temporary folder? Use `$TEMP` environment variable? Any other ways via some WinAPI calls?

Thanks.

Comment: Your best bet might be [mkdtemp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdtemp) with an `#ifdef`, Look here: [Creating a unique temporary directory from pure C in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287475)

Comment: You can find possible solution in raw C++ here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379956/how-to-create-a-temporary-directory-in-c

Comment: Thanks, but actually the main question is about 'which root temp path should I use, and should I rely on /tmp'. I have a wrapper which uses `mktemp()` but I need something instead of `/tmp` to feed there.

Comment: I'd rather use the environment variable. You never know how a Windows system is set up.

Comment: IIRC, MinGW is not a POSIX emulation layer, unlike MSYS2. So you need to use DOS paths and conventions such as the `TEMP` environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I ended up by using getenv("TEMP") and this works pretty well.