# Create folder temp in mac using lotuscript

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have tried to make a directory using MkDir in Lotusscript. I want to create a Temp folder in Mac. It does not allow me to create /Users/Temp/.

What are other alternatives to create a Temp in Mac. Example creating it /Users but name of users e.g. /Users/name/Temp. In this case how do you use lotus script to create Temp folder for any users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way. It works if you put it in shared /Users/Shared/. Thought to share to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible do this with [mkdtemp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkdtemp.html) the standard c library call, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379956/how-to-create-a-temporary-directory-in-c). In LotusScript you would want a function declaration like this :

```
Declare Function mkdtemp Lib "libc" ( template as String ) as String
```

and call it using something like :

```
Dim template As String*512 
Dim tempFolder As String*512

template = "/tmp/myFolderXXXXXX" & chr(0)
tempFolder = String( 512,0 )
tempFolder =  mkdtemp( template )
```

I  don't have a mac so this might need a tweak to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Difference between creating a folder in /Users vs. /Users/yourname is that in Users you do not have rights to write (or create folder), while you can write in your home directory (/Users/yourname).

The problem to create subdirectories in /tmp is the same - you do not have the rights.

Your best bet would be to use Environ$("TMPDIR") that returns a path to a temporary directory for the current user. There you can create your own folder.

To create a portable code, you could probably loop through "TMP", "TEMP", "TMPDIR" variables until you find one returning a value. This way you can find temp folder on Windows as well. On Linux you do not have an environment variable, but /tmp is writable for everyone.