# How to convert base64-encode image to a PNG in imagemagick?

Tags: c++, image-processing, imagemagick, png, base64

I have a base64-encode data. Eg `data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhIA...`, and I want to convert it to a PNG with Magick++. This is my code:

```
std::string data = "data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhIA...";
std::string output;     //this is the output PNG data
Magick::Blob input_blob((void*) data.c_str(), data.length());
Magick::Image input_image;
input_image.magick("INLINE");
input_image.read(input_blob);

Magick::Blob output_blob;
input_image.write(&output_blob, "PNG");
output.assign((char*) output_blob.data(), output_blob.length());
```

The code works, but when the base64-encode data is very big, the code line  `input_image.read(input_blob);` will crash.

Can anyone tell me if the code is right or how to convert base64-encode data to a PNG in magick++?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Inline image format](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php#supported) requires data exceeding 5000 characters to be referenced from a file, and can not be read directly as blob data.

Options:

- Parse and [decode base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180947/base64-decode-snippet-in-c) data into a binary blob, and pass to ImageMagick::Image
- Write data to a [temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022487/how-to-create-a-temporary-text-file-in-c), and use the `inline:` prefix

Example:

```
input_image.read("inline:/path/to/base64.txt");
```