# How do I make a file of specific size in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

**How do i make a dummy file**?

I'm using Visual C++ for a form and I need it to make a dummy file.
I know how to use things like `fstream` to write to files but how can I do it so that I know the exact size of the resulting file?

I already tried `fstuil` but that's a CMD command (yes i know you can use system()) whereas i want pure c++.

Comment: What is a dummy file? An empty file?

Comment: Do you mean a temporary-file? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022487/how-to-create-a-temporary-text-file-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (creates a 1MB file):

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs("foo.bar", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
    ofs.seekp((1024*1024) - 1);
    ofs.write("", 1);
}
```